# How to I get the jQuery UI attributes on my elements to get generated after the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When using the jQuery mobile framework many simple elements get special attributes added to them during the page load to make them looks pretty.  I want to be able to add new elements to my page, but have these elements have all of the proper attributes.  I am currently loading the page and then doing an ajax call to retrieve some data and using that data to create new elements on the page, but when I do that they don't get the attributes generated.  How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize them after your AJAX call completes. Most of the widgets have an associated jQuery plugin function, similar to regular jQuery plugins.

Example - textinput has an associated textinput function

```
$('input').textinput();
```